# Regex format change order Notepad++

Tags: regex, format, notepad++

hi i am trying to fix this format

```
11-12-2013;tisbeari;sascha091973@freenet.de:4d2bd5aa5353f8f10af4ff5f46fb1cd6
```

to this

```
sascha091973@freenet.de:4d2bd5aa5353f8f10af4ff5f46fb1cd6
```

i tried this regex **(\w+);(\w+);(\w+):(\w+)** replace with **$3:$4**
but it isn't working can u help me

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed myself Next time if you don't want to help or don't know how to help please ignore the post not leaving negative reputation

Find:

```
^(.+?);(.+?);(.+?):(.+?)$
```

Replace:

```
$3:$4
```

Comment: Rather than grumbling, please read the [help] pages and take the [tour] to learn about the rules here on Stack Overflow.